# How to get messages for specific user by FQL or GRAPH API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

I would like to retrieve all messages from  https://graph.facebook.com/me/inbox or via FQL for specific user like: "All messages from and to user with ID: 123456789"

I will be possible with FQL multi-query ?

Answer (score 3):

```js
var fbid = your_fbuid_here;
    FB.api({
                method: 'fql.query',
                query: 'SELECT thread_id, author_id, created_time FROM message WHERE thread_id IN (SELECT thread_id FROM thread WHERE folder_id = 0) AND author_id = ' + fbid + ' ORDER BY created_time ASC LIMIT 1'
            }, function ( threadresponse ) {
                FB.api({
                    method: 'fql.query',
                    query: 'SELECT thread_id, body, author_id, created_time FROM message WHERE thread_id = ' + threadresponse[0].thread_id + ' ORDER BY created_time ASC'
                }, function ( inboxresponse ) {
                        //do stuff here with results
                });
            });
```

[facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook)[facebook-fql](/questions/tagged/facebook-fql)[facebook-api](/questions/tagged/facebook-api)[facebook-graph-api](/questions/tagged/facebook-graph-api)[facebook-fql-query](/questions/tagged/facebook-fql-query)

Comment: First query will select only threads authored with friend's uid user. If the thread was authored by the current user, there will be no results.

Comment: hey, I was wondering if there's a new better way to to this? This only returns messages authored by the friend.

Answer (score 1):

> I will be possible with FQL multi-query ?

Yes **it is possible** when the inbox belongs to an authenticated app user with the appropriate permissions granted.